# Event Sourcing and CQRS in Akka.NET

Tags: c#, akka, cqrs, event-sourcing, akka.net

I'm new to Akka.NET (and Actors in general) and have some questions regarding event sourcing and CQRS in Akka.NET

Lets say for example that I have an Orders bounded context (as in Orders in an online store)

```cs
class OrdersAggregate
{
    public OrdersAggregate()
    {
        Command<NewOrder>(o => HandleNewOrder(o));
    }
    
    void HandleNewOrder(NewOrder o)
    {
        Persist(o, e =>
        {
            // update state
        });
    }
}
```

What would be the best way to implement a read store(s) around these orders (for example, having a dedicated read store for the UI)?

I see that it's possible to send events after a command was persisted, like this

```cs
Persist(o, e =>
{
    // update state
    Context.System.EventStream.Publish(e);
});
```

Then I could just subscribe to that message and pipe it into an actor that's responsible for storing the messages in a database that would serve as my read store, but it looks like this approach is error prone since there is no way to guarantee that the event publishing won't fail. (normally, without Akka, I would use something like the outbox pattern to ensure that persistence and event delivery happen in a transaction).

So is this a good way of sending events to build a read store or is there a better way to do it?

My second question is very similar. What is the best pattern for sending cross domain events (across bounded contexts) in Akka.NET?
For example, I want to subscribe to `NewOrderCreated` events from the warehouse bounded context

It looks like using the `Context.System.EventStream.Publish` would suffer from the same problems I've just described.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Akka.Persistence.Query](https://getakka.net/articles/persistence/persistence-query.html) is the right tool for implementing CQRS on top of Akka.Peristence. This allows you to periodically read in events from an Akka.Persistence journal after they've been committed and can be used to create projections and materialized views.

You can see a large-scale example I implemented using Akka.Persistence.Query and Akka.Cluster here: https://github.com/Aaronontheweb/InMemoryCQRSReplication

Comment: Hi you mentioned "periodically read in events", does that mean the reading has to be scheduled in somehow? Can I subscribe to the events and get the events whenever the occur? Is it possible to use Akka.Persistence.Query for this purpose?

Comment: Yes it can @DavidY - Akka.Persistence.Query has perpetual queries that run indefinitely and discover new events based on offsets (usually timestamps or sequence numbers). They typically work by polling data that uses specific tags or entity ids from the database periodically and publishing it to all subscribers. Does that help answer your question? And is there any other information I can provide you with that might help?

Comment: Thank you so much @Aaronontheweb! That's very helpful! The learning curve is fairly steep for Akka.Net. What do you think is the best way to learn it?